# Pop up shows at the top

Tags: java, android

I have just created simple pop up with list items but when I click on Grid item it show the pop up at the top of the page like this [image] all I need I want to show this pop up below the item grid
this is my onClick

```
gridView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), gridView1);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getActivity(),
                        "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show(); //showing popup menu
        return true;

    }
});
```

this is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/newCheck"
        android:title="New Check"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settleCheck"
        android:title="Settle Check"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/newGuestCheck"
        android:title="New guest Check"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/discountCheck"
        android:title="Discount Check"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/printCheck"
        android:title="Print Check"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: what if you change `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), gridView1);` to `PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);`?

Comment: @mic4ael thanks alot bro it works fine now :)

Comment: It looks as if you're anchoring the PopupMenu to the `gridView1`, but not the acutal `view` object you want it to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), gridView1);
```

to this

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);
```

so it will set the anchor for the menu to the proper element.